# Lowercase all but the first column

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I make all but the first column lower case?

like:

```
1 ONE
2 TWO TWO
3 THREE THREE THREE
```

required output:

```
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three
```

Comment: so, you just want to lowercase the values on all columns but first?

Comment: yes all columns except first.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but since decimal digits don't have a "case", can't you just lower-case the whole thing e.g. `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < file`?

Comment: @steeldriver just post that as answer

Answer (score 5):

You could use GNU `sed`'s lowercase `\L` extension:

```
sed -r 's/([^ \t]+\s)(.*)/\1\L\2/' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` use ERE
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `([^ \t]+\s)` save some characters that are not space or tab, followed by a space or tab
- `(.*)` save any number of any characters
- `\1\L\2` print the first saved part unchanged, then the second saved part lowercased

Answer (score 3):

`awk` with iterating over all but the first field, and converting the strings to lowercase using `tolower()` function:

```
awk '{out=""; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) out=out" "tolower($i); print $1out}' file.txt
```

---

`paste`, `cut`, and `sed`, with help from process substitution:

```
paste -d ' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file.txt | \
                                          sed -E 's/([[:upper:]])/\L\1/g')
```

This has the caveat of opening the file twice.

---

With only `bash`, using parameter expansion to convert cases:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r i j; do echo "${i} ${j,,}"; done <file.txt
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
1 ONE
2 TWO TWO
3 THREE THREE THREE

$ awk '{out=""; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) out=out" "tolower($i); print $1out}' file.txt 
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three

$ paste -d ' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file.txt | sed -E 's/([[:upper:]])/\L\1/g')
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three

$ while IFS=' ' read -r i j; do echo "${i} ${j,,}"; done <file.txt
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three
```

Comment: You don't need to use 2 variables for `read` command in your pure-bash solution.   For example, ` var="123 TEST ONE"; echo ${var,,}` will output `123 test one` perfectly fine

Comment: Serg, Here and in you solution, you have assumed that the first field is numeric, while that is true for the example OP provided, but might not be the case always, so I have provided generic solutions.

Comment: That's a good point.

Answer (score 3):

**Perl** approach with the use of `lc()` function:

```
$ perl -lne 'print lc($_)' < input.txt                                                       
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three
```

**Python** approach:

```
$ python -c "import sys;print ''.join([l.lower() for l in sys.stdin])" < input.txt                
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three
```

- send input file as `stdin` to the python command using `<` shell redirection
- using `sys` read all lines using list comprehension (the `l for l in list` structure), while simultaneously using `.lower()` method
- the resulting list of lines is joined into one string and printed out

If you want to remove trailing newline, you can do so by adding single comma at the end for Python 2 (which is default for `python` command ):

```
$ python -c "import sys;print ''.join([l.lower() for l in sys.stdin])," < input.txt
```

For Python 3, the print function is different, and it has different way of stripping trailing newline - via `end` keyword:

```
$ python3 -c "import sys;print(''.join([l.lower() for l in sys.stdin]),end='')" < input.txt
```

---

Previous approaches assume that first column is numeric as in OP's example. For generic approach where we want only non-first columns to be converted, we can do this in perl:

```
$ cat input.txt
1 ONE
SOMETHING TWO TWO
$!@# THREE THREE THREE

$ perl -ane 'print $F[0]; print map { " " . lc($_)} @F[1..$#F];print "\n"' < input.txt        
1 one
SOMETHING two two
$!@# three three three
```

In python for the sake of readability, we can do a script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    words = line.strip().split()
    case_words = [ word.lower() for word in words[1:]   ]
    print( " ".join([words[0]]+case_words)  )
```

Which works like so with the same input as in perl example:

```
$ ./lowercase_columns.py < input.txt
1 one
SOMETHING two two
$!@# three three three
```

Comment: @Zanna answer edited to include removing trailing newline, as requested

Comment: The python on- liner lowers the whole line, not just *from* the first column.

Comment: ...and so the first perl one- liner as far as I can see.

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, because it operates on example OP provided. I've also added generic solution below. Any questions ?

Answer (score 2):

A late one:

Just for fun, another python approach:

```
python3 -c "for l in open('f'): l = l.split(' ',1); print(l[0], l[1].strip().lower())"
```

Where `'f'` is the file, between quotes.

This approach assumes the file does not have empty lines.

#### Explanation

- Each of the lines is first split on *the first* occurrence of the delimiter.

  ```
  l = l.split(' ',1)
  ```
- Subsequently, the second part (all columns but the first) is lowered:

  ```
  l[1].strip().lower()
  ```
- and the combined result is printed:

  ```
  print(l[0], l[1].strip().lower())
  ```

#### Example output

On a file:

```
EEN AAP OP EEN FIETS
2 EEn banaan IS LEKKER
MIJN tante in Marokko
1 ONE
2 TWO TWO
3 THREE THREE THREE
```

The output is:

```
EEN aap op een fiets
2 een banaan is lekker
MIJN tante in marokko
1 one
2 two two
3 three three three
```